# How to insert date into MySQL with php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have the following php code :

```
<?php
require_once ('./db.php');

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db ,$port);
$dir = "Files";
$files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array(".","..")) ;
//error_log(count($files));
for($i = 2 ; $i < count($files)+2 ; ++$i){
    $d = date ("Y-m-d", filemtime("Files/".$files[$i]));
    //error_log($d);
    $insertFilesQuery = "INSERT INTO fichier (Name,Modified) VALUES ('".$files[$i]."','".$d."')";
    $resultInsert = mysqli_query($conn,$insertFilesQuery);
    //sleep(2);

}
?>
```

I want to get all the files in a directory and add their name and last modified date (yyyy-mm-dd) into mysql db.
The table fichier has 4 columns : Id, Name, Modified, OwnerId, with the type of Modified being a DATE.
The code runs with no errors but nothing is inserted into the db.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `phpmyadmin` is a tool, not the database.

Comment: Simple date is working like $d = date ("Y-m-d");

Comment: check for mysqli_error after query. print `$insertFileQuery` to see if it's correct. Try with a dummy-date '2017-12-08'. Check table definition of field `Modified`. ...a lot of self debugging possible!

Comment: Please add `or die(mysqli_error($conn));` at the end of your query and let me know if it outputs an error.

Comment: @mario I know that, sorry for that error

Comment: @TheCodesee I did what you suggested and I knew where my fault was.

Comment: @TheCodesee you resolved my problem thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

Does `filemtime` give correct timestamp ?

can redirect you to http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-notes

but have you [just test that](https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=php%20date%20to%20mysql) ?

```
date($format, strtotime(filemtime($file)));
```